# What is the appropriate way to reference a file?

Tags: c++

I’m new to linking in code and had this issue for quite a while. I’m trying to reference a file using the file path. I was wondering if I needed to reference the full path (like all the way to C: in Windows) or if I could reference the path in a shorter way.

Comment: Well there are absolute and relative paths. I am not sure this is a c++ question. It seems more of an OS question. What I mean by this is `c++` doesn't typically give you more than what the OS gives you in this regard.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question seems to be less about programming, and more about general computer software. This question would get better results if asked on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Sorry, Jesse even tho my account is old I’m quite new to this site.

Comment: @Technomancer There are lots of questions about relative paths on Superuser but you need more context about where you are using it. An absolute path is one that begins with a '/' or a drive letter and a backslash on Windows. Otherwise it is a relative path (relative to your current directory).

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to it in a shorter way. As long as the file and the program exists in that locations there won't be an issue.